# How can I embed in my site a CAPTCHA from another site, resolve it MANUALLY, send back to the original site and get the TOKEN?

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, captcha

The intention is not to resolve CAPTCHA automatically. Every user of my site will have to resolve the CAPTCHA.

The intention is to use free data from another site. These data are public and free, but to avoid massive requests, they are protected with CAPTCHA.

This is what I've done but doesn't work:

1. Create a proxy.php that manage and forward the requests to the original site.
2. Copy all headers from the original request (request of the CAPTCHA) and add them to the proxy. So, this is the form to resolve the CAPTCHA:

xxx is my site, example.com is the site that I want to resolve captcha and get data:

```
<img id="imgCaptcha" src="https://xxx/proxy.php?curl=https://example.com/Captcha&type=image&lang=it" style="width:200px;">

<input type="text" id="captcha">

<button type="button" id="btn_resolve">Resolve</button>
```

3. On button click, send the input text and check if it is resolved:

xxx is my site, example.com is the site that I want to resolve captcha and get data:

```
    $('#btn_resolve').on('click',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var captcha = $('#captcha').val();

       $.get('https://xxx/proxy.php?https://example.com/Captcha&type=check&captcha='+captcha, function(data, status) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       });
   });
```

The result is always `{"result":false,"token":"","message":null}`

I think that the problem is with JSESSIONID cookie that I set in the proxy.php, but seems filtered out from Chrome with this motivation: "This cookie was blocked because its path was not an exact match for or a superdirectory of the request url's path".

Honestly I've got not clear if I can do this and how to do this: it seems that last versions of Chrome blocked some coockies. How can I do this with PHP CURL bypassing Chrome filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it adding all needed cookies in proxy.php file.

Proxy.php forward the request using curl.
This is a good starting point for a cross domain proxy in PHP that uses CURL commands
[PHP CORS Proxy by softius](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy)

Then you can read JSESSIONID from after requesting the CAPTCHA image, and forward it to the proxy and add it and the others to the request:

```
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=name; SameSite=None; Secure');
header('Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=XXXXX');
if (isset($_REQUEST['jsessionid'])) {
    setcookie("JSESSIONID", NULL, 0, "/");
    header('Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID='.$_REQUEST['jsessionid']);    
}
```